# not able to invoke a perl script from a c shell script

Tags: perl

i am a writing `csh` script that invokes a perl script. The perl script loads some `.pm` files  but one of the `.pm` file is giving errors, i do not know perl scripting, please help.

```
Can't exec "uname": No such file or directory at /grid/cic/common/bin/../modules/plat.pm line 67.
```

Answer (score 0):

uname is not in the executing user's path.  You'll have to change the user's permissions or do a setuid.